# Group By Year and Month in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with 25 date columns. Now i am building an application in PHP and have to show a month and year based summary. I have mentioned the Source table layout and expected Summary table below.

Here `ID` represents each row. Source table `ID` will be used in the summary table. The summary table will be created per year. I need some help to prepare this summary table. Here I would like to mention that i will have around 30K rows on the source table.

**Source Table:**

```
ID  |  DATE 1      |  DATE 2        |   DATE 3
--------------------------------------------------
1   |  2017-01-14  |   2017-01-19   |   2017-01-25
2   |              |   2017-03-19   |   2017-03-25
3   |  2017-03-15  |                |   2017-05-25
4   |  2017-04-24  |   2017-05-19   |   
5   |  2017-04-10  |   2017-06-19   |   2017-07-25
6   |  2017-05-11  |   2017-06-19   |   2017-08-25
```

**Summary Table**

```
ID  |   YEAR | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |   2017 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
2   |   2017 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
3   |   2017 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
4   |   2017 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
5   |   2017 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0 
6   |   2017 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |  0
```

Comment: Do you mean that your table has 25 different date columns?

Comment: I fail to see a question and an attempt with what you're trying to do. What you have there doesn't look efficient.

Comment: And what are you trying to get in the summary table? Counts of occurrences of each month? And why are all the rows for 2017?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, I have 25 date columns. There is a year column in the summary table as these will repeat on the next year, 2018 and will continue

Comment: It's going to be really ugly: something like "select ... , case when extract(month from date1) = 1 then 1 else 0 end + case when extract(month from date2) = 1 then 1 else 0 end ... + case when extract(month from date25) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as JAN, .... It will not perform well although 30k rows is not a lot.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am trying to count the number of occurrences of dates on each month.

Comment: I am so sorry that you have to deal with data formatted like that.

Comment: why not use MySQL's built-in features https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html such as [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and a substring and `COUNT()` / GROUP BY that?

Comment: @KevinPostlewaite thanks for reading the question. It could be a very long query. there could be an another option to store 25 dates in rows but on that case the total row could will be 750K

Comment: @nasirkhan: you would definitely be better off to store a single date per row, it will be much easier to work with the data and your summary query will be much simpler. (750k rows is really not a lot, plus you will not be limited to 25 dates per id)

Comment: Stop. See normalisation. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unpivot the data and re-aggregate it.  The structure of the query is:

```
select id, year(date) as yyyy,
       sum( month(date) = 1 ) as Jan,
       sum( month(date) = 2 ) as Feb,
       . . .
       sum( month(date) = 12 ) as Dec
from ((select id, date1 as date from source) union all
      (select id, date2 as date from source) union all
      . . .
      (select id, date25 as date from source) 
     ) d
where date is not null
group by id, year(date)
order by id, year(date);
```

The `. . .` means fill in the blanks.

Comment: You sir, are faster than "White Lightning".

Comment: @gordon-linoff it works perfectly for my case. thanks.